# Running a php5 background process under Linux

Tags: php, process

There are several entries on this subject, for example [here](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/) and [enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288584/nohup-run-php-process-in-background), but none of the suggestion does seem to work. I have an example here:

```
$pid = shell_exec("nohup sleep 10 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
echo $pid;
```

which I expect to start a new command `sleep 10` in the background, and return immediately to the shell. But the found behavior is that this code 'waits' for the execution of the subcommand `sleep 10`.

How can I run my commad in the background as a new process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some notes to [`nohup` on the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), some shells deny to close unless all streams are free again.

A workaround therefore is to redirect all three standard streams: output, error and input, like in the following example:

```
nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

It is merely a guess, but that could probably be the case in your scenario.

```
$pid = shell_exec("nohup sleep 10 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null & echo $!");
echo $pid;
```

You might want to give this a try. I hope this is helpful even in case it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Alex: Okay, you deleted your comment: `$!` might return the PID from `nohup` because that is the command in the background. Did it solve now for you?